# ubuntu 14.04 amd graphics

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, graphics

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Toshiba laptop with ati 4200 graphics and it keeps shutting down and it tells me to update graphics driver how do I do that

Answer (score 1):

Boot into recovery mode and *nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf* then locate the Device section and find the line *Driver* and set it to *"vesa"*

Save it and reboot. That should handle most video cards out there and allow you to get your drivers set up.

Good luck!